# How can I export static HTML pages from next.js when they need data from a third-party API?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, next.js, isomorphic-javascript, static-site

I’m using next.js to [build static HTML webpages](https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/static-html-export).

One of my webpages needs data from a third-party API, which I’d like to fetch at build time and bake into the resulting HTML.

I don’t want this call to ever happen on the client, because:

- CORS prevents the request from succeeding anyway
- I would have to expose an API key on the client (no thank you)

I thought `getInitialProps` was the answer, because the fetched data is indeed baked in during the build/export process, but when I navigate away from the page and return from it, `getInitialProps` gets triggered on the client, breaking everything.

My current code in getInitialProps is something like:

```
static async getInitialProps(){
    // Get Behance posts
    const behanceEndpoint = `https://www.behance.net/v2/users/${process.env.BEHANCE_USERNAME}/projects?api_key=${process.env.BEHANCE_API_KEY}`
    const behanceRes = await fetch(behanceEndpoint)
    let behancePosts = await behanceRes.json()
    // Return only the required number of posts
    return {
        behancePosts: behancePosts
    }
}
```

Any advice or best practice on how to handle this? I know [Gatsby.js](https://www.gatsbyjs.org) does it out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

one possibility would be, if you just want to execute this once on the server to check if the req parameter is present in getInitialProps: ([Documentation](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/))
`req` - HTTP request object (server only).

One dirty approach:

```
  static async getInitialProps({ req }){
if (req) {
  // only executed on server
  // Get Behance posts
  const behanceEndpoint = `https://www.behance.net/v2/users/${process.env.BEHANCE_USERNAME}/projects?api_key=${process.env.BEHANCE_API_KEY}`
  const behanceRes = await fetch(behanceEndpoint)
  let behancePosts = await behanceRes.json()
  // Return only the required number of posts
  return {
      behancePosts: behancePosts
  }
} else {
  // client context
}
```

Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately, it didn't work for me.
I ran into this error `"dr.getInitialProps()" should resolve to an object`, and the page showed "An unexpected error has occurred.". It looks like I have to return something when getInitialProps() runs from client side.
So I tried to return a default value(such as { "id": "" }), then I got a blank page.